# A simple series expansion which seems to be wrong

Tags: series-expansion

Trying to answer [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4742594/taylor-expansion-of-frac-operatornamearctanhx1x2/4742613?noredirect=1#4742594), I made the following input

```
FullSimplify[SeriesCoefficient[ArcTanh[x]/(1 + x^2), {x, 0, n}]]
```

I shall not type the results but,

- not only they seems to be wrong (the first one is given as $\frac {8+\pi}8$ instead of $1$)
- they cannot evaluate (`Indeterminate`)

What could be happening ?

Comment: yes, it is a bug.

Comment: MMA version 13.3  Windows. For n=1 I get: 1

Comment: I forgot to precise that I am using version 13.1.0.0

Comment: MMA Version 13.3 Mac I get the incorrect result.

Comment: @DanielHuber not for me. I am using V 13.3 on windows 10 and do not get one. Here is screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bDIW.png)

Comment: to OP, you do not need to "type" the result, you can just post a screen shot using the palette  SE Uploader.

Comment: @Nasser: If one sets n=1, one get: 1 If n is undefined, one get  ((8+Pi)/8 for n==1. It is a bug.

Comment: another form of the coefficient:  `expr = Derivative[n][Function[x, ArcTanh[x]/(1 + x^2)]][0]/n! // 
   FullSimplify;
expr /. n -> 1 // FullSimplify`

Comment: Interestingly, `Series` seems to give a correct result:  `x - (2 x^3)/3 + (13 x^5)/15 - (76 x^7)/105 + (263 x^9)/315 + O[x]^11]`

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Yes, Series is correct. Also `SeriesCoefficient[ArcTanh[x]/(1 + x^2), {x, 0, n}]]` is correct, but only if you given specific value for `n` in the call itself.  i.e. `SeriesCoefficient[ArcTanh[x]/(1 + x^2), {x, 0, 1}]` is correct and gives 1

Comment: `FullSimplify@
 SeriesCoefficient[ArcTanh[x]/(1 + x^2), {x, 0, n}, Assumptions -> n == 1]` gives yet another answer.

Comment: Here's a workaround, strangely without the bug: `an = D[ArcTanh[x]/(1 + x^2), {x, n}]/n!`. Can check explicit terms with `FullSimplify@Table[an /. x -> 0, {n, 0, 10}]`.

Answer (score 4):

```
$Version

(* "13.3.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (June 3, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

f[x_] = ArcTanh[x]/(1 + x^2);

m = 13;

seq = {#, SeriesCoefficient[f[x], {x, 0, #}]} & /@ Range[m]

(* {{1, 1}, {2, 0}, {3, -(2/3)}, {4, 0}, {5, 13/15}, {6, 0}, {7, -(76/105)}, {8, 
  0}, {9, 263/315}, {10, 0}, {11, -(2578/3465)}, {12, 0}, {13, 36979/45045}} *)

coef[n_?EvenQ] := 0

coef[n_?OddQ] = Evaluate@Assuming[Mod[n, 2] == 1,
   FindSequenceFunction[seq[[1 ;; ;; 2]], n] // FullSimplify]

(* 1/4 (2 LerchPhi[-1, 1, 1 + n/2] + π Sin[(n π)/2]) *)
```

Comparing with the original sequence,

```
seq === ({#, coef[#]} & /@ Range[m] // Simplify)

(* True *)
```

Checking some numeric values,

```
f[#] == NSum[(DownValues[coef][[2, -1]] /. n -> 2 n - 1 // 
       Simplify)*#^(2 n - 1),
    {n, 1, Infinity}, NSumTerms -> 50, WorkingPrecision -> 15] & /@
 RandomReal[1, 10, WorkingPrecision -> 15]

(* {True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True} *)
```